# PHP check for values before the loop to check

Tags: php

I have a JSON multi-dimensional array of products from Shopify that I am looping through. Each product has 3 options and each option can have infinite numbers of values.

For example:

- Lamp (product)

  - Glass Finish (option)

    - Clear (value)
    - Smoke (value)
  - Metal Finish (option)

    - Polished Chrome (value)
  - Drop (option)

    - 600mm (value)
    - 800mm (value)

Within the loop I am creating rows within a 'repeater' field in a CMS (one for each option and then a repeater within each option for each value).

This is all fine BUT I want to do a few checks as the array of products is cached to every 30 minutes so if the cache was updated and either an option was removed or a value to that option was added then it should update.

I have my first check in place (loop through all the existing repeater options that have been added, before doing anything, and if an option already exists then skip it (and thus not creating multiple of the same options).

**What I need to do is to check each of the values to see if any new ones have been added. I can write the code to actually add the value to the repeater field but I am unsure how to check as by this point, if the option already exists, it skips over.**

Any thoughts?

```
foreach($product['options'] as $option) {

    foreach($p->shop_product_options as $options) {

         // If this option already exists... then skip the parent loop on this product
        if ($options->global_text == $option['name']) {
            continue 2;
        }

    }

    $options = $p->shop_product_options->getNew();
    $options->of(false);
    $options->global_text = $option['name'];
    $options->save();
    $p->shop_product_options->add($options);
    foreach($option['values'] as $o) {
        $values = $options->shop_product_options_option->getNew();
        $values->of(false);
        $values->global_text = $o;
        $values->save();
        $options->save();
        $options->shop_product_options_option->add($values);
    }
    $options->save();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, it seems you are already checking, without knowing what is in `$options->global_text`

Comment: I am checking the first part but I also need to check `$option[‘values’]` but obviously if the first part skips then it won’t check but even if the first part hasn’t changed (and skips) the other part could.

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure I am completely understanding what you are after but it sounds like you need something like this :

```
foreach($product['options'] as $option) {

    $optionNames = array_column($options, 'name');
    $options = $p->shop_product_options->getNew();

    foreach($option['values'] as $o) {

        $values = $options->shop_product_options_option->getNew();

        if($values->global_text === $o && in_array($option->global_text, $optionNames, true)) {
            continue 2;
        }
        $values->of(false);
        $values->global_text = $o;
        $values->save();
        $options->shop_product_options_option->add($values);
    }

    $options->of(false);
    $options->global_text = $option['name'];
    $p->shop_product_options->add($options);
    $options->save();
}
```

`array_column` will create an array getting all the values of a multidimensional array when the key is `name`, and then the if statement will look for a combination of `name` and `value`.

And since the saving logic for the option is below the loop for the values,
it will check the cache before saving anything, this might not be a copy/paste answer, i'm just giving you some logic to work with